# Use of "Container" as model name in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, model, doctrine, reserved-words

I have a entity called `Container` in a Symfony application, which I have included in the `schema.yml` file:

```
Container:
  columns:
    id:    { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name:  { type: string(127), notnull: true }

Strain:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    ...
    container_id: { type: integer }
    ...
  relations:
    Container:  { foreignAlias: Strains }
```

Then I have regenerated the models, forms and filters using the `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes` task.

Now when I try to use `$strain->getContainer()`, e.g. in a `showSuccess` action, it returns no object at all. I have double-checked that `container_id` has a reference to a record in `container` table.

Moreover, when I try to edit a `Strain` object and unlink the relationship with `Container`, the form is saved correctly, but the `container_id` column keeps the old value.

Do you know if `Container` is a reserved word or something like that in Symfony or Doctrine? What can be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't a reserved word.
(In fact, I have a model in my project with a `Container` relation).

Have you tried setting the `local` property on `Container` relation to `container_id`?